# How to bounce the ball off a collider and destroying it using trigger?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I am making a [Breakout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakout_(video_game)) game. 
I have bricks with box colliders and the ball is a rigidbody2d with circular collider.
I have applied the PhysicsMaterial2D on the ball with bounciness set to 1 so the ball is bouncing off the bricks as intended. 
Now I want to detect this collision in C# so I could destroy the brick but I cannot enable the isTrigger property as it will disable the collisions in that brick. 
So, I am looking for a way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using trigger, use OnCollisionEnter2D.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

This fires whenever a collision is detected, and should do exactly what you need.

Comment: That worked. Can't believe this was so easy. I should've researched some more. 
Thanks for the help. This is my first day learning Unity.  :)

Comment: No worries. We all gotta start somewhere. Good luck in the future!